# Changing the state of bottom navigation tab

Tags: android, kotlin, tabs, bottomnavigationview

I have a question about changing the state of the menu button.
Let's say I'm on the File tab and there is a link to Envelop tab. If I click on it I get redirected to Envelop tab. But the problem is that the Envelop tab at the bottom doesn't become red as Files right now on the picture.
It happens because I don't actually tap on that menu button and don't change its state of it. How can I change the state outside without tapping on it?

[image]

In MainActivity menu is used like that:

```
 private fun bottomNavigationView() {
        binding.bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener { item ->
            when (item.itemId) {
                UiResources.home -> {
                    router.replaceScreen(screensNavigator.getScreen(ScreenOne))
                    true
                }
                UiResources.time -> {
                    router.navigateTo(screensNavigator.getScreen(ScreenTwo))
                    true
                }
                UiResources.id.envelope -> {
                    router.navigateTo(screensNavigator.getScreen(ScreenThree))
                    true
                }
                UiResources.id.files -> {
                    router.navigateTo(screensNavigator.getScreen(ScreenFour))
                    true
                }
                else -> false
            }
        }
    }
```

In Fragment I use the following code:

```
 fastLink.onClick {
                vm.navigateTo(Screens.envelopeScreen())
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved similar situation on my project by adding color selectors:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_navigation_menu_color_selector"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_navigation_menu_color_selector"
```

And in selector you define the color's for it's selected attribute. Create a xml file named `bottom_navigation_menu_color_selector` under `res/color` folders and paste this code to it. (If the is no color folder just create it, and you can change colors as desired):

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item
       android:color="@color/colorPrimaryVariant"
       android:state_selected="true" />

   <item
       android:color="@color/colorPrimary"
       android:state_selected="false" />
</selector>
```

And one final thing cancel default behavior by adding below code to your bottomNavView right below you specify it:

```
binding.bottomNavigationView.itemIconTintList = null
```